# How to obtain a file stored in alfresco repository from JavaDelegate - serviceTask?

Tags: java, workflow, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

Greetings to the community! I am using `alfresco community edition 6.0.0` and currently I am trying to implement a workflow where i have a `serviceTask` calling a custom class implementing the `JavaDelegate` class.

**serviceTask in bpmn** code:

```
<serviceTask id="delegate"
                 activiti:class="org.nick.java.GenerateDocument"
                 name="Get the document">
</serviceTask>
```

**Java Delegate class**

```
public class GenerateDocument implements JavaDelegate {
    @Autowired
    RelatedContentService relatedContentService;

    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        ProcessEngine p = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();

    }
}
```

what I would like to do is the service task calls the GenerateDocument class, I could somehow retrieve a document that is stored inside my alfresco repository (I know it's name and it's id in case there is a method needed).

Ideally, if I retrieve this file, I would like to perform changes on it and save it as a new file in the alfresco repository? Is the above scenario feasible? According to my so-far search on the web i will may need this `RelatedContentService relatedContentService` to do this, is this correct?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something that is cool about JavaDelegates running in Activiti embedded within Alfresco is that you have access to the ServiceRegistry. From there you can get any bean you might need.

For example, suppose your JavaDelegate needed to run an Alfresco action. You can use the ServiceRegistry to get the ActionService, and away you go:

```
    ActionService actionService = getServiceRegistry().getActionService();
    Action mailAction = actionService.createAction(MailActionExecuter.NAME);
    mailAction.setParameterValue(MailActionExecuter.PARAM_SUBJECT, SUBJECT);
    mailAction.setParameterValue(MailActionExecuter.PARAM_TO, notificationEmailAddress);
```

In your case, if you want to find a node, you probably want to use the SearchService to run a query or to find a node using its node reference.

Take a look at the Alfresco foundational Java API to see the collection of services that are available for finding, updating, and creating nodes.

Comment: thanks for your reply, indeed I made use of the SearchService as you adviced and it works fine, i can perform different kind of queries in the repository and retrieve NodeRef objects. Currently i have retrieved the NodeRef of a .docx file inside my repository and I would like somehow to get the content (the actual .docx file) as stated on the second part of my question, should I choose to make use of the FileFolderService for the above scenario?

Comment: Take a look at ContentService: https://docs.alfresco.com/community/references/dev-services-content.html

Comment: thanks a lot, i managed to retrieve my file stored in the repository using the `ContentReader` like below:

`Map<Object, Object> registeredBeans = Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getBeans();
        ServiceRegistry registry = (ServiceRegistry) registeredBeans.get(ActivitiConstants.SERVICE_REGISTRY_BEAN_KEY);
        FileFolderService fileFolderService = registry.getFileFolderService();
ContentReader contentReader =  fileFolderService.getReader(nodeRef);
 InputStream inputStream = contentReader.getContentInputStream();`
and then converted the inputstream object to a file